# Why isnt php xpath working on this site?

Tags: php, xpath

I have this simple php code to print out all the links on a specific page on Agoda.com. However, for some reason the xpath is not detecting any html to query. Does anyone know why xpath wouldnt work on this site and how I can fix it?:

```
$url="http://www.agoda.com/world.html";
$html=file_get_contents($url);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath0 = new DOMXPath($dom);
$locs = $xpath0->evaluate("//a");


for ($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++) {

$location=$locs->item($x)->nodeValue;
$locationurl="http://www.agoda.com".$locs->item($x)->getAttribute('href');

print("$x. $location,$locationurl<br />");
}
```

Comment: did you bother checking what came back from the f_g_c call? You're just assuming you got some HTML and that it got parsed properly by DOM... using `@` to suppress errors is bad form.... it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalala can't hear you".

Comment: Yes both are installed and yes and I did check, there is html received. It just wont parse by xpath. If I do not suppress errors, it outputs: 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: AttValue: " expected in Entity Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Couldn't find end of Start Tag input in Entity, I attempted to use HTML Tidy and libxml_use_internal_errors, both do not make it parse.

Comment: They *show* you the error - but you need to listen to them. Then seeing the error might enable you to make it parse. But you need first to listen, understand and then fix it accordingly. There is no way around. You won't get an auto-fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies not with the XPath evaluation, it has to do with the loading of the document HTML.

[Validating the agoda.com page](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.agoda.com%2Fworld.html) will reveal that the page contains a *zero* character:

> 3. **Error**: Saw U+0000 in stream.
>
> At line 99, column 1859
>
> `693=B&amp;1676=&amp;1778=B&am`

*Zero* characters prevents the DomDocument from loading the HTML properly. Unless you are the owner of that page and can fix that bug at the source, you will have to deal with this problem yourself in some way.

The following example would remove any *zero* characters in the HTML string before loading:

```
$url  = "http://www.agoda.com/world.html";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = preg_replace('/\x00/', '', $html); // Add this line
...
```

The XPath would then evaluate as expected.